# How to select multiple person for same project

Tags: django-models

I am having doubt regarding using multiple values for same project

Basically I have 3 models
1-Company Table,
2-Project Table,
3-Contact_person Table

So, in project table I want to assign multiple values of contact person
That is I can have multiple contact_person for a single project
From a specific company

Project table fields are

"Company table Fields"

Company_Id,
Company_name,

"Contact person Table fields"

Company name(Foreign key),
Contact person name,

"Project Table"

Company name(Foreign key) ,
Project name,
Contact person(foreign key)

So here in project table in contact person field I want to have multiple contact person, from that same company

So can anyone write me out model for  contact person table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to make a relationship one to many for company to project and one to many for both company and project to contactperson.
Try to make a many to many relationship between contactperson and project. Once it is done your model will work fine.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
In this way you can add multiple Contact persons for a Project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend many to many relationships, register model, create a view, and use it in HTML. It should work fine.